# Is it possible create a collision effect with UIImageView without SpriteKit? SWIFT

Tags: animation, sprite-kit, uikit, collision

I want to animate UIImageView's falling from the top side of the Phone and when they touch the lower side they should jump up also when they touch each other after that they should move to someplace. I know that this is possible with SpriteKit (collision detection) but is it also possible without using SpriteKit(something like UIKit)?

Comment: You probably want to search about UIKit Dynamics.

Comment: Tank you! That is what I wanted.